# Create a single tkinter GUI to run any python script by defining the path

Tags: python, csv, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

I am interested to create a single tkinter GUI in which i can define a path to run a python script located in a particular folder. The code is shown below. It can read the required .py file from the set of files in that folder using the path i have given and open the dialogue box for plot graphs too but doesnt do anything. When i click the plot graphs button rather it gives an error `"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'display_graph'"`.  Can anyone check and edit my code to help.(I am using spyder so tk is tkr). I know about py2exe, So i would appreciate if someone can help with tkinter GUI code. Thanks

> My python script is Empdata.py and i used def display_graph(data) in it:
>
> Code

```
import glob
import tkinter as tkr
import os

path = r'C:\Users\C253271\Desktop\Empower data\\'
allpyfiles =glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.py"))

for file in allpyfiles:
    file =('Empdata')

def graph():    
    global v
    file.display_graph(v.get())  

root = tkr.Tk()
v = tkr.StringVar()
tkr.Button(root, text='Close',command=root.destroy).grid(row=2, column=1)
tkr.Button(root, text='Plot Graphs', command = graph).grid(row=2, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You might want to consider reformatting that huge paragraph at the start of your question. It's very hard to read.

Comment: What exactly is `for file in allpyfiles: file = ('Empdata')` supposed to be accomplishing?

Comment: @ScottHunter.. i have different python scripts in one folder which i created for different data analysis. All are working well as required. The idea was to pick up and run any particular .py file using tkinter GUI.For exp, in this case like Empdata.py from set of .py files in that folder. Not sure if it is right way to do it

Comment: @MustafaYousuf: I only asked about that one snippet; it is assigning a tuple with the single string 'Empdata' to `file` repeatedly, ignoring the actual values in `allpyfiles`.

Comment: @ScottHunter.. Thanks. would you be able to help in terms of code? I have tried ,manytimes but i am not able to figure out

Comment: @MustafaYousuf: Not until you can explain what this particular bit of code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @ScottHunter.. i have already explain that in detail.. i just need to create tkinter GUI which can run any python script. I have shown my code that i tired. I am a new user, if i knew enough, wouldnt have ask for help. If you cant help. Thats fine. Thankyou

Comment: You have not even tried to explain the particular code I quoted.  If you can't even explain what you *want* it to do, how can you expect help with *how* to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In the code from the question, `file` is a string. It thus does not have any methods. What you really want to do is to import the python file, such that its content is available.

To do so, you may use `importlib`

```
f = importlib.import_module("Empdata") # if you have Empdata.py in your folder
f.some_method()
```

Your example should therefore look something like

```
import Tkinter as tkr
import importlib

fn = "Empdata"
f = importlib.import_module(fn)

def graph():    
    global v
    f.display_graph(v.get())  

root = tkr.Tk()
v = tkr.StringVar()
tkr.Button(root, text='Close',command=root.destroy).grid(row=2, column=1)
tkr.Button(root, text='Plot Graphs', command = graph).grid(row=2, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I already have a code which does the same thing as you have shared. As long as the Empdata.py is in the same folder. But I am looking for a code which can run Empdata.py from any other folder. Is there anyway to do that where we can define a path in tkinter to a particular python file to run it? Appreciate your help.